# IIS Express10, removing https from configuration prevent site from running

Tags: iis

ASP NET MVC5 web application, Visual Studio 2015, IIS 10

Along the development I had to implement SSL. I just cannot say why, maybe Conveyor by Keyoti, maybe Elmah, maybe a local smtp server.. something required it. It's not really that important.
Having to test the application upon deployment on a remote server I have now to remove the https stuff. So I click on my project, then F4 to open the property window. Set SSL Enabled = False, check applicationhost.config.

```
<site name="xyz" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\NucLuke\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\test\xyz\xyz/>
                </application>
                <bindings>                    
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51003:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

Everything looks just fine. So I close VS, start it again, run website getting no errors but

> Unable to connect

IIS Express running application panel shows everything is fine:
[image]

How can I trace what's going on? 
If the problem was on website I should be able to track it at debugging, but that doesn't seem the case. Is there a way to trace IIS Express?

Comment: You might get started by reviewing the project file according to https://blog.lextudio.com/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration-834f88c8e8b

Comment: @:lex Thanks, but it looks like there's nothing wrong in both csproj and applicationhost.config files. Also binding matches in both (http://localhost:51003). I don't get any error IIS related, but something is asking for SSL and the browser opens the url "https://localhost" which cannot obviously be served. Also note the "https://localhost:44324" keeps reappearing (and working in browser, if I manually point to it) even if it is not reported in any of above-said configuration files. Looks like some installed extension/application is forcing the configuration to rewrite and look for SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Something was forcing the application to switch to SSL and I could not remember WHAT. My bad, but I suppose that is not so uncommon when you work for quite a long time on development implementing several extension.
In my particular case implementing Google login required SSL to be turned ON and a

> [RequireHttps]

attribute in HomeController. This attribute was accountable for forcing IIS to modify config files in order to serve the home page as https. Hope this can help someone else not to lose one day looking for such a silly error.